# What does lsmeans report for a generalized linear model, such as Poisson mixed model (fit with glmer)?

Tags: r, mixed-model, poisson-regression, lsmeans, lme4-nlme

I am analyzing the eye-tracking data from a designed experiment. A simplified version of my data looks like this (You can get the dput() data [here](https://www.sugarsync.com/pf/D315881_05804680_037112)),

```
head(lookDATA)

  participant fixationImage fixationCount
1           9    Automobile            81
2           9          Bird            63
3           9         Chair            82
4           9           Dog            64
5           9          Face            90
6           9         Plant            75
```

where participant is a unique identifier for each subject, fixationImage is what picture category they fixated on, and fixationCount is the number of times they fixated on that picture category.

I fit a poisson model to the data using glmer() from the [lme4 package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lme4/lme4.pdf).

```
model<-glmer(fixationCount ~ fixationImage + (1|participant), family = poisson, data = lookDATA)
```

I used lsmeans() from the [lsmeans package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/lsmeans.pdf) to examine the differences among the factor levels,

```
cld(lsmeans(model,"fixationImage"))
```

which provides the following output:

```
fixationImage   lsmean         SE df asymp.LCL asymp.UCL .group
Chair         3.786022 0.05764923 NA  3.673018  3.899026  1    
Bird          3.866201 0.05750641 NA  3.753476  3.978925   2   
Dog           3.868768 0.05751010 NA  3.756037  3.981500   2   
Body          3.883644 0.06040952 NA  3.765230  4.002059   23  
Plant         3.893327 0.05746744 NA  3.780679  4.005975   23  
Automobile    3.901939 0.05745528 NA  3.789315  4.014563   23  
Face          3.946848 0.05832549 NA  3.832519  4.061178    3
```

According to my (perhaps limited) understanding of the [using lsmeans](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lsmeans/vignettes/using-lsmeans.pdf) vignette the lsmean column should represent the average number of looks to a given category predicted by the model.

However, these values seem uncomfortably far from simple descriptive statistics for these numbers,

```
summaryBy(fixationCount ~ fixationImage, data = lookDATA)

  fixationImage fixationCount.mean
1    Automobile           55.18750
2          Bird           53.25000
3          Body           57.12821
4         Chair           50.39450
5           Dog           53.82883
6          Face           56.76389
7         Plant           54.71429
```

suggesting perhaps that I do not correctly understand what the lsmeans represent here, or perhaps that I've misspecified the model.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The output represents predictions from your model for each image. With the poison family, the default link function is the natural log - so those values are on the log scale. If you do `lsmeans(..., type = "response")`, it will back-transform the predictions to the original response scale.

Comment: Thanks so much for the swift answer. I changed my syntax to cld(lsmeans(model,"fixationImage",type="response")) but got the following error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "sep", value = ",") : replacement has 1 row, data has 0. For the record I am using R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31) 'Pumpkin Helmet' and lsmeans version 2.17. Nonetheless, you've answered my question and I will transform the output manually. Thanks again!

Comment: Update: Error persisted upon update to R version 3.2.0 (2015-04-16), "Full of Ingredients"

Comment: I'm not sure why the error occurs but it looks like it comes from the `cld` side of things. Take it out and see if it works. And use `pairs` instead of cld to test the comparisons (in a separate call). That's a better route anyway because cld makes black-and-white decisions.

Comment: Thanks again. You were correct, functions fine outside of cld(). I agree with your assessment about the superiority of pairs(). I plan to use the cld() output for plotting and include a table with the more detailed information from pairs() in the supplementary materials. Awesome package, keep up the great work.

Comment: @MarcusMorrisey I have fixed the bug in `cld` that created the error. **Thanks for reporting it.** Send me an e-mail (see Maintainer field) if you want me to send the updated package. Else it'll be updated on CRAN in a few weeks.